# Cannot Write to Multiple Locations Using Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write to 2 locations in Firebase: "Polls" and "Trending".

I have done so successfully, however I noticed that my first write is italicizing the specific "key" that I added and not listing any fields, whereas the second write is indeed showing all of the associated fields. Why is this so and is this considered best practice? I am surprised that the same key was created since I called `.add()` in 2 separate methods.

```
            //write to Firebase Cloud Firestore
            mStoreBaseRef.collection("Polls").add(pollMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentReference docRef = task.getResult();
                        String key = docRef.getId();
                        Log.v("KEY", key);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        CollectionReference pollAnswerRef = mStoreBaseRef.collection("Polls").document(key).collection("answers");
                        //TODO: need to add answers
                        for (int i = 0; i < mPollAnswers.size(); i++){
                            pollAnswerRef.document(String.valueOf(i + 1)).set((poll.answerConvert(mPollAnswers, i)), SetOptions.merge());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            //TODO: write to multiple locations in Firebase; check this location for epoch > 24 hours dated and delete with Cloud Functions
            mStoreBaseRef.collection("Trending").add(pollMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentReference docRef = task.getResult();
                        String key = docRef.getId();
                        Log.v("KEY", key);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        CollectionReference pollAnswerRef = mStoreBaseRef.collection("Polls").document(key).collection("answers");
                        //TODO: need to add answers
                        for (int i = 0; i < mPollAnswers.size(); i++){
                            pollAnswerRef.document(String.valueOf(i + 1)).set((poll.answerConvert(mPollAnswers, i)), SetOptions.merge());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you are using the following line of code:

```
mStoreBaseRef.collection("Polls").add(pollMap).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */)
```

You are writing the `pollMap` inside `Polls` collection, which is correct. Then in the `onComplete()` method you are using the following line of code:

```
String key = docRef.getId();
```

Which will return the exact id that was generated when you wrote the above `pollMap` to the database. So passing this key as an argument to the `document()` method inside the following line of code:

```
CollectionReference pollAnswerRef = mStoreBaseRef.collection("Polls").document(key).collection("answers");
```

Means that you are overriding all the data under the following location:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- Pools (collection)
          |
          --- d7kjSLqvM1qyS5t07Jxx (document)
```

So everything under this location will deleted and new data will be added. This is happening in the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one. As seen in your first screenshot, nothing else remains under that location but the new collection `answers` that has just been added. In order to solve this, you need to use `update()` method instead of `set()` method.

Regarding the second write, you are adding the same `pollMap` but this time under `Trending` collection and as seen in the second screenshot everything works fine because you don't use other write operations on the same reference **but** using again the following line of code:

```
String key = docRef.getId();
```

A new id is generated and using it in the following line of code:

```
CollectionReference pollAnswerRef = mStoreBaseRef.collection("Polls").document(key).collection("answers");
```

It will end up creating new data, on the same reference as in the first write. See, you are using the same collection `Polls`? This is most likely the reason why you are having more documents in the first collection rather then in the second.

Regarding the same id, I have tested several times the same code as yours or the `document()` method without passing any arguments and each time different ids were generated. I think you somehow manually created a write operation with that id.

As a conclusion, set up the correct references in your code, delete the data that you already have in your database and add fresh one, should solve your problem.

Comment: Have you sovled the issue? Is now everything alright?

Comment: I am still working through, I am not sure why I had the same ID in each node, that is baffling to me

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Is there everything alright? Have you solved the issue?